# RecyclerView set wrong height for items when I scroll

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm an android newbie and have seen similar questions here before. I have followed the given advice and set the layout_height to wrap_content without any success.
What am I doing wrong? Snippets of my code follow: MainActivity.java contains

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        // Layout manager that allows the user to flip through the pages
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // getSupportFragmentManager allows use to interact with the fragments
        // MyFragmentPagerAdapter will return a fragment based on an index that is passed
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));

        // Initialize the Sliding Tab Layout
        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.tab_indicator);
        // Connect the viewPager with the sliding tab layout
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

    }
```

activity_main contains

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <!--app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay" />-->
    <!--app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"-->

    <!-- The sliding tab -->
    <com.src.xxx.stab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"-->

    <!-- The pager that allows us to swipe between fragments -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Each tab_fragment contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please show us the layout out for the RecyclerView items and also the Code for RecyclerView Adapter

Comment: `wrap_content` in height attribute is always going to cause some problems. Try some constant values or `match_parent` or weights.

Answer (score 2):

If you set wrap content then the height would be set based on the data, if you need a fixed height set a fixed height in dp.Example

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

The row height should be kept as constant in order to get same height for each rows, example 20dp instead of wrap content.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the layout parameters of **your item views** (not activity_main or tab_fragment).

```
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
```

https://medium.com/@gabri.mariotti/recyclerview-23-2-0-and-item-height-15b08eb06573